How do I access an object instance from other modules
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

How do I make this instance accessible from other modules?

Note that if you are using Logger namespacing, logging.getLogger(__name__) will return the Logger of the current module of the current app. You might not want this in another app’s module because you might want to use that of the new app’s module. Having said that, it is always a good idea to use Logger namespacing.

use builtins
do something like
import builtins
import logging

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
builtins.LOGGER = _logger

now you can access _logger in your whole project as builtin type object with name LOGGER

Simply import the variable instance into the namespace you intend to use it in:
module.A
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
module.B
from module.A import logger
The variable instance logger is now available in namespace module.B.
You will have this variable instance referring to the same object and available to the new namespace iff you do not unbind [python-docs] this variable instance from what it refers to or (re)bind [python-docs] it to another object.
I made a comment on an engineering detail you should be aware of in your specific use case.
